# Stored Procedure with a xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to get the data from a field in a SQL server table. It is stored as a xml and I wanted to get each node value in a different row.
The xml sample is like this:

```
<id>{a75f61ce-6627-489f-83bb-d03fc880b764}</id>
<rows>
    <row>
        <columns>
            <column name="ec_date" value="15-November-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
            <column name="ec_amount" value="160" type="System.Decimal" />
            <column name="ec_description" value="viaje en coche" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_factura" value="0" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_item" value="105.01" type="System.String" />
            <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
        </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columns>
            <column name="ec_date" value="16-November-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
            <column name="ec_amount" value="2.55" type="System.Decimal" />
            <column name="ec_description" value="2 horas de parkin" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_factura" value="0" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_item" value="15.04" type="System.String" />
            <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
        </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columns>
            <column name="ec_date" value="17-November-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
            <column name="ec_amount" value="200" type="System.Decimal" />
            <column name="ec_description" value="taxi a burgos" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_factura" value="0" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_item" value="15.06" type="System.String" />
            <column name="DefaultKey" value="3" type="System.Int32" />
        </columns>
    </row>
</rows>
```

Can somebody tell me how to get each < row > element in a sql row with each different column values?

Thank you all

Comment: If the construction of this XML is under your control I'd strongly recommend to use ISO8601 for dates (`yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`). Your format is culture and language dependant and might pass all internal tests but break on a customer's system due to a tiny difference like *December vs. Dezember*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to parse an `Xml` column in a table, you'll want to use XQuery. Here's an example of how you would go about this - it will return one row per `row` xml element:

```
SELECT
    Rows.col.value('(column[@name="ec_date"]/@value)[1]', 
        'DATE') AS EcDate,
    Rows.col.value('(column[@name="ec_amount"]/@value)[1]', 
        'decimal(10,2)') AS EcAmount,
    Rows.col.value('(column[@name="ec_description"]/@value)[1]', 
        'varchar(max)') AS EcDescription
    -- .. etc
FROM
    MyTable mt
    CROSS APPLY
        mt.XmlCol.nodes('//rows/row/columns') 
      AS Rows(col);
```

`(column[@name="ec_date"]/@value)[1]` loosely translates to "find me the first column element with the `name` attribute of value `ec_date` and return me the value of the `value` attribute.

[With a Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/720a2/1)

**Obligatory Caveats**

Although the xml `column` attribute names and types seem consistent, it seems there is a type system embedded in the data - i.e. an attempt to provide the ability to dynamically change the type of the columns would make this very messy indeed.

On the other hand, of all data in your Xml document has a strong schema, then I would argue that Xml is a poor choice for data modelling - it would have been better to have normalized out `row` into it's own table. Xml is a verbose format, which repeats the schema (i.e. wastes space), and can be difficult to parse and filter.

Comment: Since there's a 1:1 relationship between 'row' and 'columns, either way works, even with multiple rows of [xml data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbc48/2). I guess I've taken the liberty of calling the wrapper 'Rows' in the aliasing, though.

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course!  Voted it up... A tiny hint: You are using `/xml` in your `Xpath`, but the original XML in the question does not show the root node. Might be misleading...

Comment: Good point - OP's original document didn't have a root and technically isn't valid, but seemingly XQuery was OK with that. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `OPENXML`

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc varchar(MAX)

SET @doc='<id>{a75f61ce-6627-489f-83bb-d03fc880b764}</id>
<rows>
    <row>
        <columns>
            <column name="ec_date" value="15-November-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
            <column name="ec_amount" value="160" type="System.Decimal" />
            <column name="ec_description" value="viaje en coche" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_factura" value="0" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_item" value="105.01" type="System.String" />
            <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
        </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columns>
            <column name="ec_date" value="16-November-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
            <column name="ec_amount" value="2.55" type="System.Decimal" />
            <column name="ec_description" value="2 horas de parkin" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_factura" value="0" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_item" value="15.04" type="System.String" />
            <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
        </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columns>
            <column name="ec_date" value="17-November-2017" type="System.DateTime" />
            <column name="ec_amount" value="200" type="System.Decimal" />
            <column name="ec_description" value="taxi a burgos" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_factura" value="0" type="System.String" />
            <column name="ec_item" value="15.06" type="System.String" />
            <column name="DefaultKey" value="3" type="System.Int32" />
        </columns>
    </row>
</rows>'

-- delete <id>
SET @doc=STUFF(@doc,1,47,'')    

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;

SELECT *  
FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'/rows/row/columns',2)   
  WITH (ec_date        date         './column[1]/@value',   
        ec_amount      float        './column[2]/@value',   
        ec_description varchar(200) './column[3]/@value',   
        ec_factura     int          './column[4]/@value',   
        ec_item        float        './column[5]/@value',
        DefaultKey     int          './column[6]/@value');

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
GO
```

I deleted `<id>{a75f61ce-6627-489f-83bb-d03fc880b764}</id>` first of all.

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Comment: @Shnugo - Thank you for information! I need refresh my knowledge about XML. I have not worked with it for a long time.